# Install latest Blender to Debian

Tags: linux, installation

I don't know how/where to put the files for Blender. From the repositories the only version available is 2.63, but I want 2.69 of Blender. Downloading the files straight from blender.org gives me an executable program, but how do I place it on the machine as if it were installed through the repositories via apt-get?

Such as shortcuts and everything.

Thanks

Comment: you can open it with the gdebi package manager and that will install it for you. This is how I did it on ubuntu

Comment: @Vader, doesn't GDebi require a .deb file?  If so, where did you get one for an updated version of Blender?

Comment: @Garrett I am not sure, which is why I left it as a comment. I just realized it comes as an executable not as .deb.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Ubuntu rather than Blender. It could be any application that you would like to manually install.

Comment: @Gunslinger it is actually about Debian ~

Comment: @Mateo close enough. The install instructions are the same for both.

Comment: @Vader Sure, but we had people wanting to migrate this to Ask Ubuntu, and would be off topic there.

Comment: @Mateo if you change all debians to ubuntu this could work on ask ubuntu

Comment: With that logic this question could be about OSX since they compile apps as a single executable like this.. Anyway I have found a similar question on U&L http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22891/where-is-a-good-place-to-put-applications-that-come-pre-compiled

Comment: It's about the OS, not blender. Whether or not it's ubuntu or debian might be important in the overall problem, but either way it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu, there's a [PPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_Package_Archive), so you can run the commands in the terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:irie/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

and you'll have one of the latest builds of Blender (read more [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/169546/173693) or visit the PPA's website [here](https://launchpad.net/~irie/+archive/blender)).  WARNING: This won't be the official stable release, but the most recent version of Blender as of a few days ago.

As for Debian, I believe that Ubuntu PPAs can [be used on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/CreatePackageFromPPA) too.  It seems like a bit of work, so hopefully someone else has a better solution.

Comment: are there the build from graphicall? are these nightly builds or stable?

Comment: This doesn't give you the official 2.69 release.  I just tested it and I got build `f1a0278` which is from 2 days ago.  I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Backporting 2.69 from Debian unstable to Debian wheezy should be straightforward. See
[How can I install more recent versions of software than what Debian provides?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112157/4671). This would also have the highest probability of working well on your system.

Installing binaries from other distributions does not work well in general, and exhibits a closed-source mentality.

Current versions in Debian include:

```
# apt-cache policy blender
blender:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.63a-1
  Version table:
     2.69-4+b1 0
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ unstable/main amd64 Packages
     2.69-3 0
         50 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ testing/main amd64 Packages
     2.63a-1 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ wheezy/main amd64 Packages
     2.49.2~dfsg-2+b2 0
        500 http://debian.lcs.mit.edu/debian/ squeeze/main amd64 Packages
```

If you want more details, please ask.