# Blender 2.63 doesn't support playback:'Blender'?

Tags: rendering, animation

<kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd> renderd simple cube movement but <kbd>Ctl</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> responded Blender 2.63 doesn't support playback:'Blender'. What's wrong? I'm just starting to learn Blender from Blender 3D Basics Beginners Guide. The supplied example file gives the same result.

System is Debian Wheezy

Comment: Are you sure you're using 2.63? If so, why don't you upgrade to 2.73?

Comment: @SixthOfFour - that's probably the version that he got with the book. Tom - 2.63 was released about 2 years ago, chances are your current system libraries are newer than what was used to create that version and may not link up 100% - [this may help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7263/935) if you have any trouble with [the official downloads](http://www.blender.org/download/) to install a newer version.

Comment: Thanks I'll upgrade. Debian is extremely conservative. Wheezy is the stable operating system and all the installable programs were frozen at the time of its release.  If I upgrade the operating system to Testing or to Unstable I can install Blender 2.72. My problem, I'll work on it.

Comment: @sambler you may want to put your comment as answer

Answer (score 1):

Books tend to use a slow release cycle and then are available for a long time. Version 2.63 of blender included with the book was released more than 2 years ago and would have been compiled using an older system version than what you have installed now. After installing newer versions of your system and supporting libraries previous releases can stop working.

The best option would be to try a new blender version. If you have trouble with the [official release versions](http://www.blender.org/download/) then you may want to look at tips on installing [builds made available by others](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7263/935) or [compiling blender yourself](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux).